# Convert Pandas Data Table to Background Gradient

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue with trying to convert my data table to a background gradient style. Every time I run the script, I'm not able to convert it somehow. I think it has to do that some data values in python won't convert right since they are in the wrong data form. Does anyone know how to help me with this issue?

```
try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    print("Wrong version")

import json

def get_jsonparsed_data(url):
    """
    Receive the content of ``url``, parse it as JSON and return the object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    url : str

    Returns
    -------
    dict
    """
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)

url = ("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/income-statement/AAPL?apikey=*******************")
print(get_jsonparsed_data(url))

data = get_jsonparsed_data(url)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sets the pandas dataframe wide for vizualization
desired_width=1000
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=desired_width)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',100)

# Gradient color
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.info()
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='Blues',
                         low=0,
                         high=0,
                         axis=0,
                         subset=None,
                         text_color_threshold=0.408,
                         vmin=None,
                         vmax=None)
print(df)
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calling .style.* doesn't convert anything.

So the print(df) in the end makes your call useless, it gets evaluated, and then nothing.

If you want to "convert your DataFrame" (you can't actually), create a new variable  :

```py
df_styled = df.style.background_gradient(...)
```

But note that

- df is a DataFrame,
- df_styled is an html representation of a DataFrame...

It's really different